# Flutter app login issues | creates new account with FB or Gmail login, but wont recognize original account created

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, facebook-login, google-signin

I am having some login issues with my app, Hallo. The issue is if you create an account either through Facebook or google login, but then decide to delete the app, when reinstall the app and log back in, it does not recognize the original account you logged-in with.

Another problem is that sometimes, when you login with Facebook to the Hallo app, it will login to a different account you are not signed in to currently via the facebook app. (i have 2 accounts on Facebook).

I have tried to make sure I was logged in with the correct account, even loggedin with FB messenger, but that does not make a difference. Deleting the app and trying again, no difference.

We are using flutter and firebase, flutter plugin for FB login.

The original account exists as well, but no way to access it via login... It works from logining in to the account from another phone, but not phone the account was set up on.